# Listview style like zebra stripes

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to do my listview as is. But I cant imagine howto do it.

[image: example ui]

Comment: Please, post your adapter code

Comment: basic custom adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom adapter, for example:

```
class MyBaseAdapter extends extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<DataModel> mItems;

    public MyBaseAdapter(List<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.mItems = data;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        }

        // set background color
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_light);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.color_dark);
        }

        // bind data here

        return view;
    }

    // other adapter logic
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @yowovogu, yes, of course, it works fine for my sample project

Comment: can youy share it with git

Comment: The code included in close-source project. I will extract it as a separate one ASAP.